# unable to find value closer to data in database php

Tags: php

I want to make a translator that translates Hindi, Tamil texts to English. I came up with a script which is giving some results but I am unable to translate a particular type of user value. 
I want to compare user input with the value in database.
I am unable to do this kind of comparison:

e.g  user input = whhhere peopples goes?
 database value = where peoples goes?

I want to handle user input as, if user enter more characters which are not in my database it should convert it into the required input

Comment: you have to specifie, what the "nearest" value is ... you could remove all double chars (using regex) and check it then. Or build an identifier from the string and check for all values inside a range around the identifier. Or you could use the string with the closest Hamming distance (only for equale string length), this would match input like (ttst instad of test)

Comment: Take a look at the "sound comparing functions" available in php. That usually is an easy and somewhat working tool for your task: http://php.net/manual/de/function.soundex.php

Comment: sound comprasion would work only for english input, not for hindi.